# Reading properties of nested elements in from-top-to-down order regardless off nesting level

Tags: json, jsonpath

Given following input data

```
{
  "foos": [
    {
      "id": "foo",
      "bars": [
        {
        "id": "1",
        "bars": []
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "bars": [
            {
              "id": "9",
              "bars": []
            },
            {
              "id": "8",
              "bars": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "bars": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get following output

```
[
  "1",
  "2",
  "9",
  "8",
  "3"
]
```

I got close with this jsonpath expression `$.foos[:]..bars[:].id`, but it changes the order of things and results in following output

```
[
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "9",
  "8"
]
```

As you can see nested elements are appended to the end of the output, but I would need them to be below the parent element.

Would be great if this was possible with one jsonpath expression, otherwise I will have to write a recursive function.

Edit: changed the id's becauase they can be actually some random number/string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change when to go recursive `$.foos[:].bars[:]..id`

Gives

```
[
  "1",
  "2",
  "9",
  "8",
  "3"
]
```